# Google Speech Recognition on video file

Tags: youtube, speech-recognition, speech

I wanna use Google Voice Service by not microphone but video file.
for example, A Video File is playing on my computer and Google Speech Recognition Program is recognizing the video's Audio stream. 
ex) Auto caption function of Youtube.
How can I use G.S.R??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great question, Google does provide a way of doing that through the Web Speech API. Here's a [link](http://www.sitepoint.com/experimenting-web-speech-api/) to an example usage, and a demo site from Google [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html).

However, you would have to extract the audio from the video first and then feed the audio to the API.

There's also the Cloud Speech API, which is free up to a certain point. It can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/speech/).

Comment: Perfect, Thank you